# Is there a way to pass extra parameters to rufus-scheduler call() or on_pre_trigger() methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

I am trying to configure rufus-scheduler for a distributed set of hosts for my Rails application. For ensuring that only one host picks up a job at a time (while the server process runs on all the hosts), I have a **DatabaseSemaphore** model, with the table structure as:

```
create_table :database_semaphores do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.datetime :locked_at
    t.datetime :unlocked_at
    t.datetime :completed_at
    t.integer  :lock_duration, :default => 30 

    t.timestamps
end
```

I have **DatabaseSemaphore.open?** and **DatabaseSemaphore.close?** methods that set the attribute values for an instance specific to each job for acquiring and releasing lock, respectively. I call **DatabaseSemaphore.open?** inside the overridden **on_pre_trigger()** and **DatabaseSemaphore.close?** inside the **on_post_trigger()** methods, respectively.

Here, **lock_duration** has a default value of 30 seconds. However, it should be alterable, for each job. So, what I intend is to be able to pass a value for it inside the scheduler block and set it as the value for 'lock_duration' attribute for that job instance inside on_pre_trigger().

Something like:

```
scheduler.in '1m', tag: 'hello' do |job|
    job.params = {lock_duration: 20}
    puts "Hello World!"
end
```

Is there a functionality to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to iterate towards what you really need.

> For that, I want to set some entries in database for each job before the job is executed

How about simply doing

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '1h' do
  # set entries in db
  2.times { DB[:entries].insert(tstamp: Time.now) }
  # do the job
  p 1 + 1
end
```

?

It's not exactly "before the job gets executed", it's more "at the beginning of the job execution".

**UPDATE**

> Would be great if rufus-scheduler's 'job' structure could allow an additional hash as a parameter, perhaps

Maybe this example could help:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

s = Rufus::Scheduler.new

s.every '5s', msg: 'hello world' do |job|
  p job.opts
end

s.join
```

It prints "{:msg => 'hello world'}" every five seconds.

It's documented in the readme under [opts](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#opts).

You could also look at [handlers](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#scheduling-handler-instances) and [co](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#scheduling-handler-classes).

Comment: Yeah doesn't exactly go with the current approach I have. Actually, I was creating a row in a DB semaphore table in the semaphore.on_pre_trigger() method, where some specific values like 'lock_duration' should be customisable across jobs. As for the above alternate suggested, I would need to move that row creation to before each job trigger in the scheduler block.

Is a decent workaround. I can go with it.Thanks :)

Comment: I have to admit that I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Would be great if rufus-scheduler's  'job' structure could allow an additional hash as a parameter, perhaps :). This would help such customisations across jobs quite handy! 
Great admirer of the current gem though. It's perfectly maintained.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit vague in the description. I'll just update the question and add a bit more details.

Comment: Oh yeah. Works perfectly. I din't realise that any generic key value pair could be passed to `job.opts`. Thanks a ton. :)